# Fourier transform of unbounded self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics, cluster-algebra

Given a nice function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{S}^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ and an unbounded self-adjoint operator $P$ acting on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, one can define a unitary operator $f(P)$ via continuous functional calculus. Moreover, we require that $f$ is represented by  a Fourier transformation
$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi(y)e^{-2\pi ixy}dy,$$
does it make sense to have
$$f(P)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi(y)e^{-2\pi iyP}dy\;?$$
Note that here $e^{-2\pi iyP}$ is also a well-defined unitary operator.

I came up with this question when reading a paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002200100412 by Faddeev-Kashaev-Volkov. There they use such arguments to show the pentagon relation of quantum dilogarithm (in the appendix).

Comment: It suffices that $f$ is smooth enough so that $\psi$ is in $L^1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I think $\psi$ cannot be a function, it should be a distribution. See, for example, $f\equiv 1$.

Comment: Right, I have missed that the values are in the unit circle.

Comment: $\psi$ is not going to be in $L^2$ or $L^1$ if you require $f$ to be unimodular.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts As I said to Ryszard, $\psi$ is a distribution.